# Do I need update docker image to fix kernel flaw?

Tags: docker

I have an application distributed as docker image basing on CentOS 7.

Also my host machine running the docker contains is CentOS 7.

Recently RedHat released 5 important patches to fix kernel flaws.

- [CVE-2017-7477](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-7477)
- [CVE-2017-7645](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-7645)
- [CVE-2017-6214](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-6214)
- [CVE-2017-7895](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-7895)
- [CVE-2017-2583](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2017-2583)

I have `yum update` the host machine

Do I need update the docker image with `yum update`?
I guess kernel flaws won't affect docker containers, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Containers uses the Host Kernel, if it's just kernel stuff you should be ok. Here's a link to a question about if containers and hosts share kernel on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not